# nodejs async nested calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I would like to scrap an url:

1 request to get a list of elements

1 request on each result to get details

Here what I have:

```
var request = require('request')
    , cheerio = require('cheerio')
    , async = require('async')
    , format = require('util').format;

var baseurl = 'http://magiccards.info';
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        request(baseurl + '/sitemap.html', function (err, response, body) {
            var sets = [];
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('a[href$="/en.html"]').each(function () {
                sets.push({"name": $(this).text(), "code":$(this).attr('href').match(/\/([^)]+)\//)[1], "path": $(this).attr('href'), "translations":[]});
            });
            callback(null, sets);
        });
    },
    function (sets, callback) {
        console.log(sets);
        async.eachSeries(sets, function (set, callback) {
            console.log('SET ' + set.code.toUpperCase());
            request(baseurl + set.path, function (err, response, body) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                $('body > a[href^="/' + set.code + '/"]').each(function () {
                    console.log('   %s (%s)', $(this).text(), $(this).attr('href'));
                });
            });
        });
    }
], function (err, result) {
    console.log('ERR');
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

The problem is that the 2nd waterfall function run only once, if I replace the eachSeries with an each, the loop does run X times (but I need to wait for result).

Wath am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call the `eachSeries` `callback` function. Otherwise `async` won't know that you are done. (1)

You also need to tell the `waterfall` function that you are done with that step, also by calling the `callback` function. (2)

```
function (sets, waterfallCallback) {
    async.eachSeries(sets, function (set, seriesCallback) {
        console.log('SET ' + set.code.toUpperCase());
        request(baseurl + set.path, function (err, response, body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('body > a[href^="/' + set.code + '/"]').each(function () {
                console.log('   %s (%s)', $(this).text(), $(this).attr('href'));
            });

            seriesCallback(null); /* 1 */

        });
    }, waterfallCallback /* 2 */);
}
```

Comment: works great, but without the 2nd callback (I don't understand why would you use a callback down there). WHen I put a callback on eachSeries, it tells me that callback is undefined (no function)

Comment: I've modified the answer to better explain the two different callbacks. Without the second one, the last function will never run. (The one with `console.log('ERR');` and `// result now equals 'done'`)